# Is it possible to use Javascript to temporarily store data while User adjusts, and then pass as Hash to Rails Controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

At a high level, building an application that allows `User` to request `Items` from other `Users` located in the same county as the requesting `User`. `User` and `Item` are both models with associated databases.

**On the request page, I'm trying to build 3 components.**

1) A map that shows

- A marker for each other `User`
- When clicked on, the marker displays a popup that lists the `Items` that that `User` has. The requesting user can click on each `Item` to add it to the list of `Items` s/he would like to request

2) A set of search fields that allows the requesting user to filter the markers for `Users` and `Items` on the map, for example, perhaps by `dates_available`.

3) A "cart" (not literally since this is not about e-commerce) that shows the `Items` the requesting `User` has currently added, with a final `submit` button. Note, `dates_available` should not only be a search field, but also part of this `Request`

A not perfect example is this screenshot from Getaround:

[image]

I'm pretty new to coding in general, so always want to think through plugins, APIs, shortcuts, etc. The below is just for reference, but if you have comments on how to implement this better, PLEASE do tell me! Right now, I am currently thinking of using:

**For the map:**

- Openlayers.org
- Gmaps.js

**For the search** (which is really a filtering capability):

- Ransack gem (https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack)

**THE KEY QUESTION**

**For the "cart" and the click `Item` to add to "queue" part**, I realize that while I can do this in Rails purely, it might be less of a positive UX experience since the page would constantly re-render every time a new item were added, not to mention it'd potentially result in excessive pings to the database or records to be created. I'm thinking of using Javascript to basically make the "cart/queue" a staging area for temporary storage, where the `User` populates it with whatever `Items` s/he wants and edits as needed, but it's not until the final `submit` click that the entire group of `Items` is passed as a Hash to the Rails Controller to be saved.

Now, since I don't really know JS very well, any resources on how to do this (easy plug-in solutions, other considerations I may have missed) or if it's not possible (in which case pray tell) would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try Javascript localStorage.

```
localStorage.myTempValue = "my temp value";
```

or

```
localStorage("key", "value");
```

You can store object:

```
var person = { name: "xxxxx", age: 35 };

localStorage.Person = person;
```

Hope my answer may trigger an idea in you!